# Html.ValidationMessageFor Text Color

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, validation

Probably a simple question, but i cant seem to find the answer.

using MVC 2 i have a series of Html.ValidationFor controls. I want to assign a CSS class to the text and cant seem to do it.

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Chest, new { @class = "textBoxMeasure" })%>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Chest) %>
```

if i try the same method as textboxfor i get errors because it requires a string, when i put a string in it still wont  work!

thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's a variant that takes htmlAttributes as the third argument (the second is the message that should be displayed, or you can use null for the default validation message)

```
Html.ValidationMessageFor(
        Model => Model.Chest, 
        "Please enter a value", 
        new { @class = "redText" })
```

For more info see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721293%28v=vs.98%29.aspx

Comment: A bit changed version which worked for me for MVC4 with bootstrap.

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Chest, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })

Comment: What if I want to keep he default message instead of "Please enter a value"?

Answer (score 24):

I added a comment to the accepted answer, but I cannot to format it for better view. So, here is my already formatted comment from the accepted response.

I had similar case and I used solution from accepted answer. But I desired to use message from model annotation. I tried this:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Chest, null, new { @class = "text-danger" });
```

and it correctly worked for me. I used MVC4 with bootstrap.

Comment: This one worked for me, probably changed in newer version.

Answer (score 10):

Use the classes assigned to the span tag holding the message. If the field is valid the class is field-validation-valid. If there is an error its field-validation-error.

I use

```
    .field-validation-error {
        color:Red;
    }
```

Comment: Way better than the other answer, but both are useful.

Comment: Best solution: keeps it consistent across all forms and avoids repeating it for each and every field.

Comment: @TraderhutGames I wouldn't say it's way better than the accepted solution; the accepted solution comes in handy as well when you need to coordinate different colors, due to darker backgrounds or vice versa. Both solutions are very useful.

Answer (score 1):

simplest way to do this to put @Html.ValidationMessageFor in div tag and apply css to div tag

```
    <div style="font-size:15px !important;">
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This way the color range will be wider.

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.WriterName, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
```