# String Length validation doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following data annotation in my model

```
[StringLength(6, ErrorMessage = "MyMsg")]
public string MyField { get; set; }
```

But on my view I get the error "NaN"

The field only accepts 0 as a value.

Why?

[Razor]

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyField)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyField)
```

Comment: Show the Razor part.

Comment: i edited the original post. @Yoda

Comment: The code you have shown has nothing to do with that error.

Answer (score 0):

Use: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyField)` instead of those you have posted.

Comment: @DouglasFranco Because it was very vague. It lacked some essental info. When you write a question on SO try to read it from perspective of person who would like to help you. This person has to know the details. It still lacks some editing, but now you provided just enough info to let me help you. If you like me answer please accept it.

Comment: i use msdn forum, and there have many prestative users then here in stackoverflow. I participate and colaborate both, but here all action i do, i get negative votes. Anyway, thank you again for the help.

Comment: @DouglasFranco I was banned few times a few years ago before I learned, you'll get it ;). SO is great. I tell all my students(I am private tutor too) to use SO, I wouldn't achieve many things without SO.

Comment: What possible difference would using `EditorFor()` make. Both `TextBoxFor()` and `EditorFor()` produce identical output which is `<input data-val="true" data-val-length="MyMsg" data-val-length-max="6" id="MyField" name="MyField" type="text" value="">`

Comment: @StephenMuecke As far as I remember the `EditorFor` will give him nice styled input field  as it will set `class` of the input field. His code could've been simplified. Besides, we don't know what version of MVC does he use and THOSE problems happened before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438439/html-validationmessagefor-text-color I still have problem for nearly a year with MVC in my opinion it is a bug in MVC app template: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920087/i-can-login-only-when-users-username-is-exacly-the-same-email-in-database

Comment: @Yoda, The html output is **identical**. And `EditorFor()` does add any class name. And unless OP is using MVC-5.1+, there is no way to add html attributes using `EditorFor()` anyway. What OP claims is happening has absolutely nothing to do with the code in the question. The property is a `string` and a `NAN` error can only be associated with a numeric value so who knows what the real code is. (The question should be closed shortly anyway)